# Legend next to vertical line plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

In Matlab, it is possible to create a legend for a plot. Now I do not want the information in the legend box, but directly next to the line as follows:

[image]

(This is only an example)

For the vertical lines, I did the following:

```
v1 = vline(14.7,'k')
set(v1,'Color','black','LineStyle','--','LineWidth',1);
```

How do I add information next to the two vertical lines (just like 14.7s and 18.6s) as in the figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function, e.g.

```
figure();
v1 = vline([14.7, 18.6], 'k');
set(v1, 'Color', 'black', 'LineStyle', '--', 'LineWidth', 1);
xlim([8,25]);

text(14.8, 0.87,'\leftarrow 14.7 s');
text(18.7, 0.9,'\leftarrow 18.6 s');
```

[image]